# UV-unwrapping problem,different results from literally the same action

Tags: uv

When i use smart uv project tool everything is fine,but after this i click on normal unwrapping button and texture turns into a mess.Every seam is stayed as it is,i do not touched anything,and yet the result is different.Why result is diferrent?

Please help!
[image: before]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. If smart UV project works, use it. No need to re-unwrap.

Comment: smart UV project creates too many seams,i thought smart UV project is just like casual unwrapping but automatically, turns out it is two independent things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to BSE,

I think you may have confused the process for UV Unwrapping.

*U > Unwrap* and *U > Smart UV Project* are two different, separate methods of unwrapping your model. They work independently of each other. In other words, if you are using Unwrap, there is no need to use Smart UV Project. If you are using Smart UV Project, there is no need to use the 'normal unwrap' function.

When using Smart UV Project, there is no need to manually add your own seams to the model. Blender will automatically calculate where the seams **should be** based on the angles of your mesh object, and unwrap the object accordingly.

The advantage of Smart UV Project is that it is a very quick method of unwrapping any object.
The disadvantage of Smart UV Project is that Blender will sometimes add seams in places you may not want.

When using the 'normal unwrap' method (U > Unwrap), Blender will only unwrap the model according to the seams you have added.

I believe the reason you are getting poor results when using U > Unwrap is because you do not have enough seams on your model, and Blender is therefore struggling to unwrap it correctly.

I cannot clearly see all of your seams from the screenshots you posted, but I would guess for a manual unwrap you would need some additional seams **at least** in the areas I have highlighted in green below:

[image]

In general, I use Smart UV project for smaller, less important objects in a scene, and I take the time to manually unwrap larger, more important objects in a scene.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!!!

Comment: Don't mention it :) Would you mind accepting my answer?